# Conjugate Classes in Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra

> How to find all conjugate classes of group S_3.

Comment: In this very particular case, two elements are conjugated iff they have the same order (can you see why?)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: @DonAntonio And in fact, this is almost the only group with that property.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Well, yes...almost the only **finite** such group. The other two are $\;S_1,\,S_2\;$ . But there are infinite groups wilder in this respect, as HNN extensions show. One can construct groups in which *any two non-unit* elements are conjugated (i.e., there are only two conjugation classes)

Answer (score 2):

In general in $S_n$ two permutation are conjugated iff they have the same cyclical structure( i mean in their decomposition in disjoint cycles the have the same number of r-cycles for all r). Try to prove this, and then the  solution follow easely